# Image appears as Text on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF DataGrid (`System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`) to display columns from a data holder object.

For every property in the object, I am displaying a column in the DataGrid. 
I am using the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to bind to a List, `Items.Refresh()` to update the DataGrid when the data changes.

The displayed columns are dynamic (the user selects what to display from settings menu), so I cannot add the columns on XAML code.

One of the properties in my data object is an Image object:

```
    public Image   Status { get; set; }
```

But when the DataGrid just displays the type of the object:

`System.Windows.Controls.Image`

Any way to display the image and not the type?

**EDIT**

DataGrid definition:

```
<DataGrid Name="ResultsDataGrid" />
```

Data definition:

```
private readonly List<ProductItem> _items = new List<ProductItem>();

public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = _items;
         }
```

The columns are generated automatically.

Comment: How do you dynamic add the columns? I guess you may need to add DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn when it's a Image.

Comment: @alex10 I am using the `Visibility` property to show the needed columns.

Comment: Visibility?So you already created the columns? As H.B said, you need `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Maybe you should paste the code how you add the columns.

Comment: @alex10 I am not creating the columns myself. I am using `ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = _items`. The _items is a `List`.

Comment: Show us more code. I am confused.....

Comment: @alex10 Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116147/discussion-between-alex10-and-giannisf).

Answer (score 0):

Is that the control class? If so, your object should not be containing those, instead maybe just a URL or a `BitmapImage`, either way you probably need to create a custom column with a data template that binds to your data accordingly.

That is: The template contains an `Image` whose source is bound to the URL or `BitmapImage`. Maybe you need a converter for the URL, or it just converts on its own.

Comment: I changed it to `BitmapImage` and now it displays the image `Uri`.

Comment: I explicitly said that you need your own column (`DataGridTemplateColumn` or custom subclass) with a data template that can handle this properly.